# Transposing rectangular region

Tags: rectangle

I have a piece of code like this in yaml.

```
security_group_sig_egress_ipv6: "allowed_remote_sig_egress_ipv6"
security_group_sig_ingress_ipv6: "allowed_remote_sig_ingress_ipv6"
security_group_int_egress_ipv4: "allowed_remote_int_egress_ipv4"
security_group_int_ingress_ipv4: "allowed_remote_int_ingress_ipv4"
security_group_int_egress_ipv6: "allowed_remote_int_egress_ipv6"
security_group_int_ingress_ipv6: "allowed_remote_int_ingress_ipv6"
security_group_om_egress_ipv4: "allowed_remote_om_egress_ipv4"
security_group_om_ingress_ipv4: "allowed_remote_om_ingress_ipv4"
security_group_om_egress_ipv6: "allowed_remote_om_egress_ipv6"
security_group_om_ingress_ipv6: "allowed_remote_om_ingress_ipv6"
```

as you can see the ":" is the delimiter between the two expressions. I want to transpose/swap the "key:value" pair in following way for the entire rectangular region:

```
allowed_remotexxxx: "security_groupxxx"
allowed_remotexxxx: "security_groupxxx"
allowed_remotexxxx: "security_groupxxx"
allowed_remotexxxx: "security_groupxxx"
```

I can use [Anchored Transpose](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AnchoredTranspose) to transpose each line separately but not the whole rectangular region. Is there a way in Emacs to achieve this with minimum keystrokes?

Comment: Using a keyboard macro comes to mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple cursors works well for these things. You can select **: "** and then invoke **mc/mark-all-like-this**.

[image: Here's a demo for your use-case]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replace-regexp` with the following patterns:

Replace 2 groups of characters separated by colon, space and quotes:

```
 ^\(.*\):\ "\(.*\)"$
```

With the capture groups swapped and reformatted:

```
\2: "\1"
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Can I run all these commands under a rectangular mark?